# mailto link doesn't add Outlook signature in letter

Tags: html, email, outlook

I (and some folks) need to send a lot of similar e-mail's everyday. Using Outlook 2010 as mail client. Today I want to somehow simplify this process.
Thinking about html page with `mailto` links. Like:

```
<a href="mailto:our@inner.mail&subject=Subject01&body=textForLetter">Letter to someone</a>
<a href="mailto:ourOther@inner.mail&subject=Subject02&body=anotherTextForLetter">Letter to someone else</a>
```

etc...

Problem is come out when I clicked on one of them. Outlooks "New message" window pops up, but without signature. It's only text from `mailto` link in body. 
Can someone point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to figure this out as well.

According to http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_26410679.html you get either the body or the signature.  I've tested this and removing my body text brought my signature back.

Alternatively, you can hardcode your signature into the body text.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is not going to fix this bug. The workaround is to add it in the email body.

I believe the following MSDN article explains what you're describing: [Messages that are created outside Outlook do not include the default Outlook email signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/outside-messages-not-include-email-signature) (KB 2544665)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you cannot customise a signature from the mailto: link.

The 2 ways to look at it is either setup your signatures in Outlook itself or, add the "signautre" to the bottom of the body included in the link?

Comment: I don't want customize. I have already set up signature in Outlook. When I create new letter in Outlook, signature shows up. When letter created by mailto - no signature at all.